# Run Python script as a standard CLI program

Tags: macos, bash, python-2.7

How do I write a simple Python script that is globally executable via a simple command (such as `cd` or `pwd`)?

I know the file has to be executable and in my `$PATH`. I know I can omit the `python` prefix when calling the file by specifying the interpreter. But then I still have to call the script using the `./script` syntax.

I basically want to create a bunch of Python CLI programs stored `~/bin` and have them behaving the same way as Bash scripts like `cd` and `pwd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `~/bin` to your `PATH`. For example, you could add something like this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

To see the changes in the current shell, you can then do `. ~/.bashrc`. The path should automatically be added in all new shells that you open. You can check by doing `echo "$PATH"` - you should see that it starts with `/home_directory/bin:...`.

Comment: Huh. I thought there was more to it. Thank you!